# How to handle JImage with missing image file

Tags: joomla-3.4, template-override

Today my website showed errors to end users on one page because an image was missing. This is an image stored in jseblod and accessed by using new JImage() in my template.

Is there a guideline on how to handle this error? JImage throws (literally) at least 3 different errors, does this indicate I should simply use try{}catch blocks, or is there a recommended way to handle a missing image

Comment: Yes, `try catch` would be a good idea, and then use `enqueueMessage` to display the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, using catching exceptions would be the best idea in my opinion, I'd then use Joomla `enqueueMessage` function to display a user friend error message, like so:

```
try
{
    // Try to do something with the image using 'JImage'
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // The image was missing
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('MISSING_IMAGE'), 'error');

    // Error message = $e->getMessage();
    // I'd then most likely log the actual PHP error to a file using 'JLog'
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, but the easiest solution would be to run an ifexists on the src prior to running the jimage. I.e:

If (JFile::exists($src)) {
//Run jimage here 
}

Alternatively you could add the images to an array and run a for each depending on your output and function.